# Bootstrap 3 grid for small and medium devices 3x3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I try this code and it is ok but what you think ?
I want this to look nice on small device too..

```
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6"> <img src="img/usluge/projektovanje.jpg" class="img-responsive img-service" alt="netbox"><br/>
      <label class="btn-service">designing</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4  "> <img src="img/usluge/laserskorezanjemetalazoom1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-service"><br/>
      <label class="btn-service">laser Metal Cutting</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4  "> <img src="img/usluge/cncprobijanjee1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-service"><br/>
      <label class="btn-service">cnc punching</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4  "> <img src="img/usluge/cnc_savijanje5.jpg" class="img-responsive img-service"><br/>
      <label class="btn-service">CNC BENDING</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4  "> <img src="img/usluge/robotsko_zavarivanje1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-service"><br/>
      <label class="btn-service">robotic welding</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 "> <img src="img/usluge/zavarivanje3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-service"><br/>
      <label class="btn-service">welding</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4  "> <img src="img/usluge/plastifikacija_4.jpg" class="img-responsive img-service"><br/>
      <label class="btn-service">Coatings</label>
    </div>
```

Is this ok? or i need do something more. I want to that look nice on small, medium and laptop devices...

Comment: It's ok. So what is your question?

Comment: well that pictures don't look good... they are streched..

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using rows and container-fluid.
Look here for more details on [sizes of grid columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options), [responsive images](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive), and other [responsive options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities).

There is also a "[thumbnail with content](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails-custom-content)" option!

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">1</div>
     <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
     <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">1</div>
     <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
     <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">1</div>
     <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
     <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For smaller devices you should start using media-queries.
That's probably what you're looking for.